# Insert a list in a list python

Tags: python, list

```
a=[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[4,4,4]]
b=[3,3,3]
```

Can I get b in the chosen position using the function a.insert ?

I tried something among those lines:
students.insert(int(args[[5]]),list)

Comment: Well, did whatever you tried work?

Comment: Is the chosen position fix or should the position be chosen so to keep the list sorted?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list` object has an `insert` method which does exactly what it says on the tin:

```
In [1]: a = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[4,4,4]]

In [2]: b = [3, 3, 3] 

In [3]: a.insert(2, b)

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
```

I'm inserting `[3, 3, 3]` into position `2` within the list `a`.

Comment: i tried just that and i got this error message:

Comment: What error message? And what version of python are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Besides to [insert()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) this is an alternative:

```
➜ ~ python3
Python 3.6.2 (default, Aug 03 2017, 16:34:42) [GCC] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[4,4,4]]
>>> b=[3,3,3]
>>> a=a[:2]+[b]+a[2:]
>>> a
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
>>>
```